# Asp.net MVC multiple uploads with strongly typed view?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got a view that is strongly typed to an object, for example let's say a car object.  The car object has a name and description.  I'd like to be able to have a dynamic number images uploaded, maybe using the Jquery upload plugin, with the the car object, as well as some meta data for the image like date taken.  So how would one use a strongly typed view and a dynamic number of image uploads?

I've found a few [examples](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) online for this but they use the creation of a new form and therefore the images would go to a different action.  Is there a way to have the car model plus the uploaded images data go to the same action?
Is this possible?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Car car, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
     return View();
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Car information</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Description)
        </div>

        <label for="file1">Filename:</label>
          <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />

          <label for="file2">Filename:</label>
          <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are going for dynamic upload following thing help you in ASP.net MVC 3.

1. [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)
2. [Jquery AJAX Upload](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/).

Now do following thing

1. Create Separate Action that take care of file upload action via Uploadify.
2. Also make sure you change file to dynamic name.
3. Create one hidden filed that take care of file names that created via Ajax.
4. Now on post of form you have car object and one hidden field for all files for Images and at last you have to map file with card object.

Hope this step help you to create your solution.